# Convert int to list of string in c#

Tags: c#, tostring, implicit-conversion

I have the following code where I convert an int to a string in a list but visual studio does not accept when I try to convert the int into string

Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'

```
listOfUsers.Add(new User
{
   Id = myReader["Id"].ToString(),
   Name = myReader["Name"].ToString(),
   Coordinate = myReader["Coordinate"].ToString()
});
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The Id property defined in User is an int but you're assigning a string to it?

Comment: Start off with showing the query please. Presumably you don't have a column 'Id' in your data reader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ID` must of `Int` type so you need to covert data to appropriate type.

Here you need to convert value to int type. You can use [`Convert.ToInt32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Converts the specified string representation of a number to an equivalent 32-bit signed integer.

Example:

```
Id = Convert.ToInt32(myReader["Id"])
```

Note: Do remember to check `myReader["Id"]` is not [`DbValue.null`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: when I do this I get an exception error.
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Comment: The problem was with my coordinate. Thank you so much

Comment: Hi @Satpal, Isn't it better to use int.TryParse()?

Answer (score 2):

You code should be , assuming Id is int.

```
listOfUsers.Add(new User
                    {
                       Id =Convert.ToInt32(myReader["Id"]),
                       Name = myReader["Name"].ToString(),
                       Coordinate = myReader["Coordinate"].ToString()
                    });
```

Comment: when I do this I get an exception error. An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```
listOfUsers.Add(new User
                    {
                       Id =int.Parse(myReader["Id"].ToString()),
                       Name = myReader["Name"].ToString(),
                       Coordinate = myReader["Coordinate"].ToString()
                    });
```